# Differences in various ffmpeg h264 encoders

Tags: video, ffmpeg, codec

Can anybody explain to me the differences in these h264 ffmpeg encoders? Does any of them use GPU accelerated compression?

```
 V..... libx264              libx264 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (codec h264)
 V..... libx264rgb           libx264 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 RGB (codec h264)
 V..... h264_v4l2m2m         V4L2 mem2mem H.264 encoder wrapper (codec h264)
 V..... h264_vaapi           H.264/AVC (VAAPI) (codec h264)
```

Comment: If you want GPU acceleration then you'll want the `-hwaccel` switch combined with relevant hardware encoder (`nvenc` or so on) that you have in your system: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- `libx264` → Open source software encoder. This one is the best, but not usually the fastest.
- `libx264rgb` → A patched version of libx264 that outputs RGB instead of YUV. This format is not commonly supported by decoders.
- `h264_v4l2m2m` → Uses whatever video encoder Video4Linux decides to use. This can vary between distros and hardware. (I think, I don't have much experience with this one.)
- `h264_vaapi` → Intel H.264 decoder